# Blackwell–Girshick equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I came across Blackwell–Girshick equation days before,but I have found nothing about it. What is Blackwell–Girshick equation? Can you give some explaination or links?

Comment: See the last part of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/86997/25632).

Comment: @Stefan That is not what I want.can you give me some references including some detailed clarifications about it?Thank you.

Comment: @JackyZhang What do you want which is not included there?